# Serve one Django app on several Apache Virtualhosts

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, virtualhost

We have a Django application served by Apache (mod-wsgi) with such config :

```
<VirtualHost vhost:80>
  # ...
  WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

We're looking to serve that single application into 2 virtualhosts : `vhost:80` and `vhost:443` ... the time necessary for the client's migration and finally only keep it on the https virtualhost.
Is it possible to duplicate the instruction `WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/wsgi.py` into a second virtualhost (`vhost:443`) or will we encounter problems running twice the same app with same DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, you want to make sure you are using daemon mode of mod_wsgi and not embedded mode. Either way, if a multi process configuration was being used, you would already have multiple instances of the application accessing the same database. That is generally not an issue. The issue is doubling up on the number of processes when adding the virtual host for SSL. This is where daemon mode comes in. The typical configuration is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName sitename.example.com

  # Define a daemon process group.

  WSGIDaemonProcess sitename

  # Specify WSGI application and delegate to daemon process group.
  # As delegating here, don't need WSGIProcessGroup/WSGIApplicationGroup.

  WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/wsgi.py process-group=sitename application-group=%{GLOBAL}

  # ... access control directives

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName sitename.example.com

  # ... SSL options

  # Specify WSGI application and delegate to daemon process group.
  # As delegating here, don't need WSGIProcessGroup/WSGIApplicationGroup.
  #
  # Note that we did not define a daemon process group in this virtual
  # host. Instead we rely on fact that can reach across and use daemon
  # process group defined in virtual host for port 80. This is possible
  # as value of ServerName is the same.

  WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/wsgi.py process-group=sitename application-group=%{GLOBAL}

  # ... access control directives

</VirtualHost>
```

Add `process=nnn` and `threads=nnn` options to `WSGIDaemonProcess` if need to tune capacity and performance. Also ensure you revise timeout options you may want to set on daemon process group.

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html

Comment: Hi, we finally had time to test that proposition. We get the following error : "WSGI process group not accessible" at the line matching the WSGIScriptAlias in 443 VirtualHost. Would something be missing?

Comment: The port 443 VirtualHost must come after that for port 80. The ServerName in each must match.

Comment: I tried it on 2 differents servers (one with many vhosts, one not), the error occurs the same on both. btw, when the 443 comes before 80, the error is different : "WSGI process group not yet configured."
I also checked `ServerName` does match in both sections.
Any other clue?

Comment: One would need to see the actual configuration you are using to be able to comment.

Comment: Here are the files :
[/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/servername.conf](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1666299)
[/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/wsgi_express.conf](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1666300)
[/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/wsgi_express.load](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1666301)

Comment: For a start, don't use a hostname in ``VirtualHost``. Use just ``<VirtualHost *:80>`` and ``<VirtualHost *:443>``. Try that and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: exactly same error.
Btw, one server is serving many vhosts ... so I'll need to name the vhost.

Comment: That is not how you name the vhost. That value is for defining specific network interfaces by IP address that you want to restrict requests being handled on. It is the ``ServerName`` field which defines what hostname that vhost handles. Using the hostname where you are is not correct. If you are doing that in all vhost's when not necessary you could be screwing up how mod_wsgi works out what is matching 80/443 pair for same ``ServerName``.

Comment: So should qualify, what you are doing by listing FQDN in ``VirtualHost`` isn't necessary if don't care what interface request comes over, use '*'. It is allowed, but the httpd documentation says it is not recommended.

Comment: Anyway, before the ``WSGIScriptAlias`` in 443, try adding ``WSGIProcessGroup servername.example.com`` and see if it errors on that line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147800/discussion-between-samb-and-graham-dumpleton).

Comment: Sorry, I don't use SO chat. Use the mod_wsgi mailing list if you want to discuss this in more detail.

Comment: ok, so i tried your suggestion and It still fails at the line of `WSGIScriptAlias` instruction.

Comment: Leave the ``WSGIProcessGroup`` and remove the ``process-group`` from ``WSGIScriptAlias``. Alternatively, try moving the ``WSGIDaemonProcess`` outside of the first ``VirualHost``.

Comment: @samb Your edit to change my answer to latest suggestion was rejected. What I provided should work. It if isn't and you found that using ``WSGIProcessGroup`` instead of ``process-group`` does, then just say so in a comment as I will need to work out why the original doesn't work as it should. There could well be a bug in the mod_wsgi code which is affecting your use case.

Comment: Ok. So YES, your suggestion to replace `process-group` instead of `WSGIProcessGroup` worked smoothly. I had panned to add a comment when edit was accepted. Thanks for your answer! I'll mark it as accepted when it works as written.

Comment: I will try and test it tomorrow and see if can work out why it isn't working as is supposed to then.

Comment: Not sure whether Apache internals has changed around how it stores information about host definitions or what, but confirmed it is not working as expected for Apache 2.4. Working on fix.

Comment: I don't know why the restriction, but the feature was specifically implemented they way it is. Release notes say """Allow WSGIImportScript in VirtualHost. When using WSGIImportScript, or
process-group option to WSGIScriptAlias, the daemon process group being
referred to now must be declared in same VirtualHost or at global server
scope.""" I don't know why it precludes reaching across to other VirtualHost with same ServerName.

Comment: Am hoping this is fixed now in 4.5.16 and behaves as I expected it to.

Comment: Thanks, I do confirm it works on both servers I encountered the problem, with `mod-wsgi==4.5.17`